# What could cause application fail with SIGABRT on lock acquiring after fiew hours of work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11, zeromq

I wonder what are general problems that could cause application fail with SIGABRT on lock acquiring after fiew hours of work?

It mostly happens in one particular class destructor code on `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(sync);`

Sometimes it happens on `boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);` that is inside   `try catch(std::exception& e)` block.

Application has no detectable memory leaks. Uses Boost, ZeroMQ, HiRedis. Code base is large so I wonder what are main things that we shall loock for? what can cause such problems (at least in theory)?

Answer (score 2):

Lock/unlock on corrupted mutex? (i.e. working with object that were deleted) <sub>Probably most of the times</sub>

Double lock within same thread?

Exception in destructor?

<strike>Parallel initialization of statics?</strike>

Comment: That is the problem - how can we get double lockonly using scoped_lock?

Comment: @DuckQueen, recursive call. This method being call directly or indirectly from this method.